# Как связать бэкэнд и фронтэнд через nginx

Tags: java, angularjs, nginx

написал учебное приложение: бэк на java(Spring boot), а фронт на angularjs. Сейчас пытаюсь запустить приложение, томкэт запускается на порту 8080. Возникли вопросы с настройкой конфига nginxб не понимаю, как там нужно прописывать путь до скомпилированного фронта. 
Конфиг nginx:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;


sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

#keepalive_timeout  0;
keepalive_timeout  65;

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   C:\projects\meteorep\meteorep-front\html;
        index  C:\projects\meteorep\meteorep-front\index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: proxy pass надо

Comment: Добавил в location строку proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1; однако приложение не запускается

Comment: Порт не указали

Comment: Добавил порт 8080, всё равно не запускается

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать nginx в качестве proxy.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  myserver.ru;

    access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8080/;  # my java server port 8080
        proxy_redirect     off;

        # дальше всякая шелуха по поводу размеров всяких буфферов, таймаутов proxy и т.п.
    }
}
```

Comment: Я верно понимаю, что это должно выглядить таким образом:                                                location / {
            root   C:\projects\task-manager-master\task-manager-master-front\html;
            index  C:\projects\task-manager-master\task-manager-master-front\index.html index.htm;
            proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8080/;  # my java server port 8080
            proxy_redirect     off;
        } Но в таком варианте всё равно не запускается..